# EXPLAIN Failed. 3706: (-3706)Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ','

Tags: sql, teradata

I've seen this error mentioned on StackOverflow, but not in the context I am using. I am relatively new to Teradata and this behavior is throwing me for a loop. Here is code that works:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (this, that) VALUES (1, 2);
```

Here is code that throws the error:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (this, that) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4);
```

This is super confusing to me because the Teradata docs have the following example:

```
INSERT INTO cities VALUES (2, 'San Jose'), (3, 'Oakland');
```

Could someone show me what am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried : `INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4);` just guessing...Do not know teradata

Comment: Yeah, I’ve tried moving spaces around. Same behavior :/

Comment: Sorry, spaces ? I have removed column names from the statement... Also please can you give us the link you are talking about: "Teradata docs have the following example" if it is online.... :)

Comment: This is the source ? https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/sql/insert.html

Comment: Are you using the github project or are you using the product sold by teradata.com? Your statement is indeed documented at the former but I don't think it's supported by the latter. At least that's what I find at docs.teradata.com?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry was walking and replying, disregard. Yes, I have tried w/o column specifications to the same avail. Here is the [knowledge base article.](https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/sql/insert.html) -- actually on further investigation, I'm not sure what 'presto' is and whether or not my company is using it. This might impact the behavior...

Comment: Teradata doesn 't support multi-row inserts (the docs are not for Teradata SQL). You must use `INSERT INTO cities VALUES (2, 'San Jose');INSERT INTO cities VALUES (3, 'Oakland');` At least you can submit it using a *Multi Statement Request* (F9 instead of F5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata only allows you to insert one record with a single `values`.  You can see this in the [syntax diagram](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/r_6Z4JwVMhANtZFCIKEx7Q/4Tyr4N42vyZG7rqVMzb3Dw) for `insert` -- there is no "backloop".

Two inserts is a simple workaround:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (this, that)
    VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO test_table (this, that)
    VALUES  (3, 4);
```